# How to test if a div is not displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, casperjs

I have a `div` with a unique `id='myDiv'`. In a CasperJS test, I need to verify that this `div` is not displayed (i.e., `display=none`).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasperJS provides the [`visible`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#visible) function in the `casper` module and [`assertVisible`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#assertvisible) in the `tester` module.

It checks

- whether `getComputedStyle` produces an exception,
- `style.visibility === 'hidden' || style.display === 'none'`,
- `style.display === "inline" || style.display === "inline-block"` and
- `elem.clientHeight > 0 && elem.clientWidth > 0` in that order.

<s>This also works if an ancestor element is hidden, but not the tested element.</s>

Comment: Why do you say it's working when an ancestor is hidden? It fails in my case (posted an issue https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/1736). Has it been working before?

Comment: @amberv I don't know anymore. Perhaps I should have been more clear what *"works"* means in this case. Now, I'm not sure anymore. I'm sure I didn't add the sentence just for fun. Perhaps I just read the source code and didn't understand it correctly. I'll remove the sentence. Hopefully, it will work in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try computed styles in vanilla-js:

```js
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myDiv')).display == 'none';
```